# How can I restrict/detect HTTP request made to my server from a mobile application that is not my own client application?

Tags: android, ios, security, uniqueidentifier, app-id

Suppose I have a mobile (android, ios) application like Facebook or Twitter, how can I make sure that the http request to my servers come from my client application only and not from any other application in the mobile device?  What are the server and client side 'assumptions' and 'security measures' for this?

I understand the concept of Mobile Device Unique Identifier and also my APP Id which can be sent from the frontend in the http request, but I assume the http request can be modified/updated by the client application right?