# How to identify that http requests made to my server are from my React Native application and not a reverse engineered version of it?

Tags: react-native, express, security, axios, httprequest

How can I identify my React Native application ?

For example if someone creates a reverse engineered version of my React Native application, how can I Ensure on my server that http requests processed by my server are genuinely made by my app and not a reverse engineered version of it or any other means ?

How can I prevent my app from being reverse engineered or altered ?

Is it possible in anyway to make my React Native code not visible even when someone tries decompiling the app bundles ? (Not by obfuscation)

I have made few research and it didn't seem like there are many possible ways to ensure the total security

Also my case is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447111/how-can-i-restrict-detect-http-request-made-to-my-server-from-a-mobile-applicati)

Even if it isn't a communication means such as http requests please suggest me something that could work for. A valid means of secure communication.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.